# Correct Verification of Regex

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I have a asp.net textbox that has to accept numbers, letters and a small set of special characters: `[~],[/],[.], [_] and [-]`

So i created the regex

```
([A-Za-z0-9\~.\-\/_ ])
```

and applied to the textbox as

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="txtParams" Width="220px" ClientEnabled="True">
                            <ValidationSettings
                                ValidationGroup="group1"
                                CausesValidation="true">
                                <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="<%$Resources:Resources, RequireValidationMessage %>" />
                                <RegularExpression ErrorText="<%$Resources:Resources, ValidateElementsMessage %>" ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z0-9\~.\-\/_ ]" />
                            </ValidationSettings>
                        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

When i test this regex on [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) it passes the test data

```
/home/File.txt~data_file10~2015-10-10
```

but my textbox rejects it and shows the error message.
I used that tester because its based on .net as to eliminate regex implementation shenanigans but here i am.

Is my regex wrong? there is no processing whatsoever going on on the textbox as of yet.

Comment: Try using `"[A-Za-z0-9~./_ -]"`.

Comment: still the test data fails on the textbox

Comment: Maybe this value requires the whole input to match. Try `^[A-Za-z0-9~./_ -]+$`.

Comment: Did you try my suggested regex?  I think it should work since [a similar one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671303/devexpress-textbox-regular-expression-validator-not-validating-correctly) worked.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i did. Now, can you make that a proper answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Posted and explained. Have a great week!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regex here should match the entire input, you need to anchor the regex at both ends with `^` (start of input string) and `$` (end of input string):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9~./_ -]+$
```

Also, it is a good idea to place the `-` at the end of the character class to avoid escaping it, and also note that `~`, `/`, `.`, `_` do not have to be escaped inside a character class to be treated as literal symbols.